# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros de imput a función de JS? Es para configurar un mapa

Tags: javascript, html5

me piden una página donde se solicite al usuario que introduzca latitud, longitud y nombre del marcador para luego darle a un botón y se genere el mapa. No logro que los valores de los ID pasen a la función como parámetros. Tengo esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
     #map {
         height: 100%;
     }

     html, body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 2px;
         padding: 0;
     }
</style>
```

```
    var map;
    function mostrarMapa() {

        var latitud = document.getElementById('latitud').value;
        var longitud = document.getElementById('longitud').value;
        var marcardor = document.getElementById('texto').value;

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: latitud, lng: longitud },
            zoom: 8
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: marcardor
        });
    }

</script>

<input type="number" placeholder="Escriba la latitud" id="latitud">

<input type="number" placeholder="Escriba la longitud" id="longitud">

<input type="text" placeholder="Escriba el texto del marcador" id="texto">

<button onclick="mostrarMapa();" id="btn_mostrar">Mostrar</button>
<div id="map"></div>



<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx"
        async defer></script>
```

¿Alguna pista? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el tipo de valores que pasas a la función. Si bien, los valores los capturas desde un `input` con `type="number"`, realmente el valor sigue siendo un `string`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea capturar el valor de Latitud y Longitud introducidos por el usuario en elementos `input` de HTML, para pasarlos a las funciones `google.maps.Map()` y `google.maps.Marker()` de la API de Google Maps. Los valores de latitud y longitud deben ser valores numéricos, según la documentación de la [API Google Maps - Coordinates - LatLng CLass](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para pasar los valores de Latitud y Longitud introducidos por el usuario, usaremos elementos `input` de tipo texto. Usaremos el atributo `pattern` con una expresión regular para validar que los caracteres introducidos sean valores numéricos válidos para las coordenadas de latitud y longitud. Los valores capturados en los campos `input` serán convertidos a tipo `Number` usando el método `parseFloat()`.

Por ejemplo, si se tiene que `value` es tipo `string` y es una representación válida de coordenada, entonces `Number.parseFloat(value)` será un valor tipo `Number` válido.

Las expresiones válidas de coordenadas vienen dadas de la forma `#.#####`, tomando en cuenta que si solo tenemos decimales, se debe escribir un cero delante del punto decimal.

Se puede realizar una validación mucho mejor, tomando en cuenta que el rango para latitud es `[-90,90]` y el rango para longitud es `[-180,180]`, pero va más allá del objetivo de este ejemplo.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

**Nota**

Recuerda reemplazar el valor `API_KEY` por tu propia `key`.

```js
// Declaramos la variable map como variable global
    var map;

    function mostrarMapa() {
        // Obtenemos los valores de latitud, longitud y marcador
        var latitud = document.getElementById('latitud').value;
        var longitud = document.getElementById('longitud').value;
        
        // markElement almacena el elemento input completo
        var markElement = document.getElementById('marcador');
        
        // Es buena idea establecer un 'default marker'
        //en caso que no se escriba un marcador en el input
        var marcador = markElement.value == "" ? "default marker" : markElement.value;
        
        // verificamos que latitud y longitud contengan valores
        if(latitud == "" || longitud == "") {
            alert('Nada para mostrar');
            return;
        }
        
        // debido a las restricciones de nuestro pattern
        // es seguro que latitud y longitud pueden
        // parsearse a Number
        latitud = Number.parseFloat(latitud);
        longitud = Number.parseFloat(longitud);

        // ahora podemos construir nuestro mapa
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: latitud, lng: longitud },
            zoom: 8
        });

        // construimos el marcador
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: latitud, lng: longitud },
            map: map,
            title: marcador
        });
    }
```

```html
<style>
     /* Establece el tamaño del elemento div que contendrá al mapa */
    #map {
      height: 400px;  /* Altura: 400 pixels */
      width: 100%;  /* Ancho: El ancho de la página */
      }
  </style>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba la latitud" id="latitud" pattern="^-?\d+\.?\d+$"> &nbsp;

  <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba la longitud" id="longitud" pattern="^-?\d+\.?\d+$"> &nbsp;

  <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba el texto del marcador" id="marcador"> &nbsp;

  <button onclick="mostrarMapa();" id="btn_mostrar">Mostrar</button>
  
  <br>

  <div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY" async defer></script>
```

Espero que esta respuesta se adapte a tus requerimientos.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

La expresión regular del atributo `pattern` debe tener la siguiente estructura: `^-?\d+\.?\d+$`, donde:

1. `^-?\d+` indica que el valor debe empezar con un dígito o más (`\d+`) y bien puede o no tener un símbolo menos (`-?`) delante del dígito.
2. `\.?` indica que el valor puede o no contener un punto para marcar el decimal.
3. `\d+$` indica que el valor debe terminar con uno o más dígitos.

Comment: Gracias, funciona. No me cargaba el mapa porque no parseaba las coordenadas a float. No tenia conciencia de que necesitase ser asi. Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

aqui este el codigo, aunque solo lo hice la greo localización por latitud y logitud, mas abajo puede encontrar el ejemplo completo

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Escriba la latitud" value="4.304871860560465" id="latitud_s">
<input type="number" placeholder="Escriba la longitud" value="-74.80346219089665" id="longitud_s"> 



<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="find_btn" type="button">Ubicar mi posición</button>
```

y el código javascript, deber tener en cuente que la variable map deber se global o si no le va a macar variable indefinida

```
var map;

function initMap(){
  // Map options
  var options = {
    zoom:16,
    center:{lat:4.302314898662877,lng:-74.80926649120488}
  }
  // New map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}

$("#find_btn").click(function (){

    var latitud_s=$('#latitud_s').val();
    var longitud_s=$('#longitud_s').val();
    if ("geolocation" in navigator){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
            console.log(position);
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
        var pos = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};//localiza mi posicion actual
        var pos ={ lat: parseFloat(latitud_s), lng: parseFloat(longitud_s) };
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        map.setZoom(19);
        infoWindow.setContent("Localización del usuario <br/>"+
            " "+
            "<a class='massmodal btn btn-success' href='#' id='massadd-modal' <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span>Añadir un Árbol</a>"+
              "  "+
            //"Lat : "+position.coords.latitude+" </br>Lang :"+ position.coords.longitude
            "");

        map.panTo(pos);


    });
        }else{
            console.log("Su navegador no soporta la Geo-localización ");
    }
});
```

aquí esta el ejemplo completo solo tiene que añadir el key de google maps

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>

            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="find_btn" type="button">
                Ubicar mi posición
            </button>

                    <input type="number" placeholder="Escriba la latitud" value="4.304871860560465" id="latitud_s">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Escriba la longitud" value="-74.80346219089665" id="longitud_s">


                <div id="map">
                </div>

<!--google maps-->
<script>
    var map;
        function initMap(){
        // Map options
        var options = {
        zoom:16,
        center:{lat:4.302314898662877,lng:-74.80926649120488}
        }
     // New map
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


$("#find_btn").click(function (){

    var latitud_s=$('#latitud_s').val();
    var longitud_s=$('#longitud_s').val();
    if ("geolocation" in navigator){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
            console.log(position);
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
        var pos = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};//localiza mi posicion actual
        var pos ={ lat: parseFloat(latitud_s), lng: parseFloat(longitud_s) };
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        map.setZoom(19);
        infoWindow.setContent("Localización del usuario <br/>"+
            "@can('Punto_Imagenes Add')"+
            "<a class='massmodal btn btn-success' href='#' id='massadd-modal' <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span>Añadir un Árbol</a>"+
              "@endcan"+
            //"Lat : "+position.coords.latitude+" </br>Lang :"+ position.coords.longitude
            "");
        $('#latitud_mass').val(position.coords.latitude);
        $('#longitud_mass').val(position.coords.longitude);
        map.panTo(pos);

        MostrarArbolesCercanos(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    });
        }else{
            console.log("Su navegador no soporta la Geo-localización ");
    }
});


    $('#acciones').attr('class', 'btn btn-success add');
    $('#acciones').text('Añadir Nuevos ');

    }
</script>


<style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
      * element that contains the map. */
     #map {
       height: 100%;
     }
     /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
     html, body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
</style>
<script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo marcos, pero estás usando Jquery, ¿no? No estoy tan avanzado, estoy empezando con JS y quería algo más sencillo, algo como lo que puse en el primer mensaje. No entiendo qué está mal y porqué no coge los valores que introduzca el usuario.

Comment: en el tercer cuadro del código le puse todo el ejemplo completo, solo necesita cambiar el key de google maps, ademas jquery es lo mas fácil de aprender y ayuda mucho a programa código mas sencillo